# Regular expression return one result on two

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing, preg-match-all

I try to retrieve result from a website but the regular expression I wrote doesn't want to return all result I have result 1,3,5... but never 2,4,6...

This is a text sample:

```
<tr>
<td style="background-color:white">Inter en attente de cloture : </td>
<td style="background-color:red">depuis +2H</td>
<td style="background-color:#FF7F00">depuis -2H</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table class="tab_script">
<tr>
<td>N° commande</td>
<td>Nom</td>
<td>Prenom</td>
<td>N° Mobile</td>
<td>N° Fixe</td>
<td>Ville</td>
<td>Code Postal</td>
<td>Num. Intervention</td>
<td>date rdv</td>
</tr>

<tr bgcolor="#E5E5E5">
<form method="POST">
<td></td>
<td>NOM 1</td>
<td></td>
<td>0600000000</td>
<td>0400000000</td>
<td>VILLE</td>
<td>12345</td>
<td><a  href="index.php?id=13&statut=2&id_inter=123271915">123271915</a></td>
<td style="background-color:red">23/11/2012 08:30</td>
</tr>
</form>

<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<form method="POST">
<td></td>
<td>NOM 2</td>
<td></td>
<td>0600000000</td>
<td>0400000000</td>
<td>VILLE</td>
<td>54321</td>
<td><a  href="index.php?id=13&statut=2&id_inter=130680172">130680172</a></td>
<td style="background-color:red">09/03/2013 18:30</td>
</tr>
</form>

<tr bgcolor="#E5E5E5">
<form method="POST">
<td></td>
<td>NOM 3</td>
<td></td>
<td>0600000000</td>
<td>0400000000</td>
<td>VILLE</td>
<td>12345</td>
<td><a  href="index.php?id=13&statut=2&id_inter=123271915">123271915</a></td>
<td style="background-color:red">23/11/2012 08:30</td>
</tr>
</form>

<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<form method="POST">
<td></td>
<td>NOM 4</td>
<td></td>
<td>0600000000</td>
<td>0400000000</td>
<td>VILLE</td>
<td>54321</td>
<td><a  href="index.php?id=13&statut=2&id_inter=130680172">130680172</a></td>
<td style="background-color:red">09/03/2013 18:30</td>
</tr>
</form>
```

And my regular expression:

```
$preg='#<tr.*?>.*?';
$preg.='<form.*?>.*?';
$preg.='<td>(.*?)</td>.*?';
$preg.='<td>(.*?)</td>.*?';
$preg.='<td>(.*?)</td>.*?';
$preg.='<td>(.*?)</td>.*?';
$preg.='<td>(.*?)</td>.*?';
$preg.='<td>(.*?)</td>.*?';
$preg.='<td>(.*?)</td>.*?';
$preg.='<td>(.*?)</td>.*?';
$preg.='<td>(.*?)</td>.*?';
$preg.='#ism';
preg_match_all($preg,$response,$match);
```

And the result:

Comment: I just saw that if I copy paste the first part I want to find several time it will be find by the preg also the problem is not my regular expression but the text itselft however I don't see any difference...

Comment: lolwut... Use an html parser already...

Comment: Look into the PHP class DomDocument. There are too many problems with parsing HTML with regular expressions, and many posts on SO about it, here is an exhaustive example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Comment: I would like it but I need the code quick and I don't know how it works, how would you do get the data in my example please ?

Comment: What he says can be done with regex. I simply believe it is not the quickest nor the simplest of the solutions

Comment: Instead of all those `.*` I would use more specific character sets like `[^>]*` or `[^<]*`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you know the format is consistent across all the file.

I suggest you to yo a line-by-line search and store the data you need.

An even better solution would be to use [PHP SAX](http://php.net/manual/en/example.xml-structure.php) which does exactly that but for XML:

The code of the link will call `startElement` every time it finds an opening tag and `endElement` for every closing tag. As you know your structure it is very easy to find the data you need